# Layout Anchor and NSLayoutConstraint are not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was(and still am) goofing around with Objective-C. I want to learn how to create UI programatically. I have a method that takes an already defined UIButton (I don't know if defined is the right word) and it customize it based on developer's input. Here is the function:

```
   +(void)configureButtonWithBoldTextTop50Left150RightAnchor160: (UIButton *)buttonToConfigure whithXParam: (CGFloat)x withYParam: (CGFloat)y withHeight: (CGFloat)height withWigth: (CGFloat)width  withTitle: (NSString *)title withTitleColor: (UIColor *)titleColor withCornerRadius: (CGFloat)cornerRadius withBorderWidth: (CGFloat)borderWidth withBorderColor: (UIColor *) borderColor withButtonBackgroundColor: (UIColor *)buttonBackgroundColor withFontSize:(CGFloat)fontSize presentIN: (UIViewController *)ViewControllerToPresentIn 
{

        CGFloat leadingAnchorValue = 150; // left
        CGFloat trailingAnchorValue = -160; // right

        buttonToConfigure = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        buttonToConfigure.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        buttonToConfigure = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        [buttonToConfigure setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonToConfigure.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helveticaneue-Bold" size:fontSize]];
        [buttonToConfigure setTitleColor:titleColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buttonToConfigure setFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

        buttonToConfigure.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
        buttonToConfigure.clipsToBounds = YES;
        buttonToConfigure.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        buttonToConfigure.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
        buttonToConfigure.backgroundColor = buttonBackgroundColor;
        buttonToConfigure.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

        // adding button to view hierarchy

        [ViewControllerToPresentIn.view addSubview:buttonToConfigure];

        [buttonToConfigure.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:ViewControllerToPresentIn.view.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
        [buttonToConfigure.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:ViewControllerToPresentIn.view.topAnchor constant:50].active = YES;
        [buttonToConfigure.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:ViewControllerToPresentIn.view.trailingAnchor constant:trailingAnchorValue].active = YES;
        [buttonToConfigure.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:ViewControllerToPresentIn.view.leadingAnchor constant:leadingAnchorValue].active = YES;
    }
```

The problem is that the Layout Anchors do not work. Also, I tried to add NSLayoutConstraint by defining(creating) it in my .h file, but when I add it to the button, the whole app crashes with Error: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT". How can I add some kind of constraints, so it looks kind of the same on all screen sizes?

Comment: What does "the layout anchors do not work" mean? The phrase "does not work" is almost never useful in asking a Stack Overflow question. Say what actually did or did not happen and what you expected.

Comment: @matt by saying does not work, I mean that there are no effects(e.g. The button doesn't change it's position) after adding the anchors or the NSLayoutConstraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the button twice. Remove the following line since you are using constraints:

```
buttonToConfigure = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

There is also an easier way to setup a bunch of constraints at once:

```
UIView *view = ViewControllerToPresentIn.view;
[view addSubview:buttonToConfigure];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [buttonToConfigure.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:ViewControllerToPresentIn.view.centerXAnchor]
    [buttonToConfigure.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.topAnchor constant: 50],
    [buttonToConfigure.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: height],
    [buttonToConfigure.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: width],
]];
```

Note that here I provide different constraints. You need to decide which constraints you really need.

Keep in mind that you need to specify a horizontal position and size and a vertical position and size. The constraints I show here are just one of several ways to satisfy that requirement.

The constraints in your question have two issues.

1. You have three horizontal constraints. Since you have both a leading and trailing, the use of `centerXAnchor` is unnecessary. The leading and trailing constraints define both horizontal position and size.
2. You only have one vertical constraint. For a UIButton this may not be an issue since the button has a default height. But your method takes a `height` parameter which you don't use (after removing the extra button creation line).

Your method has an x, y, width, and height but none of your constraints use any of those parameters. So you need to decided what is necessary.

Comment: I have made some changes with the code you have provided and It actually works. Thank you very much!